# How to add next and previous buttons to my pager row

Tags: jsp, jstl

How would I add next/previous buttons to this snippet, cause as you can see ,it will display as many links as it needs, so if you have a high number of pages then this might not be the best solution

```
 <c:choose>
   <c:when test="${pages >1}">
        <div class="pagination art-hiddenfield" >
             <c:forEach var="i" begin="1"end="${pages}" step="1">
                  <c:url value="MaintenanceListVehicles.htm" var="url">
                      <c:param name="current" value="${i}"/>                
                  </c:url>
                  <c:if test="${i==current}">
                       <a href="<c:out value="${url}"/> " class="current" >
                           <c:out value="${i}" /></a>
                  </c:if>
                  <c:if test="${i!=current}">
                       <a href="<c:out value="${url}"/> " >
                           <c:out value="${i}" /></a>
                  </c:if>
              </c:forEach>
         </div>
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
       <div align="center">                   
       </div>
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

CSS:

```
.pagination .current {
    background: #26B;
    border: 1px solid #226EAD;
    color: white;
}
.pagination a {
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid #226EAD;
    color: #15B;
    text-decoration: none;
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    padding: 0.3em 0.5em;
}
.pagination {
    font-size: 80%;
    float: right;
}
div {
    display: block;
}
```

This is what I get with my current code:
[image]
And this is what I'd like to display, with ellipsis if possible
[image]

Hope you can help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And after thinking it for a while, I came up with a work around  to make this work. It really isn't very elegant but it gets the job done. Here is the code.

```
   <c:choose>
        <c:when test="${pages>1}">
            <div class="pagination">
                <c:if test="${current > 1}">
                    <c:url value="MaintenanceListVehicles.htm" var="prevUrl">
                        <c:param name="current" value="${current - 1}"/>                           
                    </c:url>
                    <a href="<c:out value="${prevUrl}"/>">Prev</a>
                </c:if>
                <c:set var="begin" value="1" />
                <c:set var="end" value="9" />
                <c:choose>
                    <c:when test="${current-4<=1}">
                        <c:if test="${pages< 9}">
                            <c:set var="end" value="${pages}" />
                        </c:if>
                    </c:when>
                    <c:otherwise>
                        <c:set var="begin" value="${current - 4}" />
                        <c:set var="end" value="${begin + 8}" />
                        <c:if test="${end >=pages}">
                            <c:set var="begin" value="1" />
                            <c:set var="end" value="${pages}" />
                            <c:if test="${pages> 9}">
                                <c:set var="begin" value="${pages- 8}" />
                            </c:if>
                        </c:if>
                    </c:otherwise>
                </c:choose>
                <c:forEach var="i" begin="${begin}" end="${end}" step="1">
                    <c:url value="MaintenanceListVehicles.htm" var="url">
                        <c:param name="current" value="${i}"/>                          
                    </c:url>
                    <c:choose>
                        <c:when test="${i==current}">
                            <a href="<c:out value="${url}"/> " class="current" >
                                <c:out value="${i}" /></a>
                        </c:when>
                        <c:otherwise>
                            <a href="<c:out value="${url}"/> " >
                                <c:out value="${i}" /></a>
                        </c:otherwise>   
                    </c:choose>
                </c:forEach>
                <c:if test="${pages> current}">
                    <c:url value="MaintenanceListVehicles.htm" var="nextUrl">
                        <c:param name="current" value="${current + 1}"/>                          
                    </c:url>
                    <a href="<c:out value="${nextUrl}"/>">Next</a>
                </c:if>
            </div>
        </c:when>
        <c:otherwise>
            <div align="center">
            </div>
        </c:otherwise>
    </c:choose>
```

Really hope that someone else finds it useful!

Answer (score 2):

### Adding Prev/Next Links

This should be fairly straight forward, but keep in mind that you probably don't want to display Prev if you are on the first page or Next if you are on the last page.

#### Prev/Next Example

Here is an example for the Prev/Next links. Add the first if block above your forEach and the second below it.

```
<c:if test="${currentPage > 1}">
    <c:url value="MaintenanceListVehicles.htm" var="prevUrl">
        <c:param name="current" value="${currentPage - 1}"/>                
    </c:url>
    <a href="<c:out value="${prevUrl}"/>">Prev</a>
</c:if>

<c:if test="${maxPages > currentPage}">
    <c:url value="MaintenanceListVehicles.htm" var="nextUrl">
        <c:param name="current" value="${currentPage + 1}"/>                
    </c:url>
    <a href="<c:out value="${nextUrl}"/>">Next</a>
</c:if>
```

### Displaying an Ellipsis

This is more complicated because it requires an algorithm and isn't something I would advise that you do using JSP EL and/or JSTL alone (since you'd likely have to use scriptlets and those are bad news). In the past, I've used a `PaginationHelper` bean class in conjunction with a JSP 2.0 tag file to accomplish this style of pagination.

Create a class called `PaginationPage` that has an integer page number and a String label. Have the `PaginationHelper` handle all of the logic for calculating the pages and have it return a list of `PaginationPages` to the tag. Then the tag just needs to iterate over the pages and output them however you'd like.

#### Pagination Logic

Here is some of the logic to consider when you implement this style of pagination:

- If there are fewer than 10 pages, then just display all pages.
- If the current page number is close to one, don't display the left ellipsis.
- Display the current page and the three pages that come before it and after it. e.g., if the current page is 14, then display 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17. You can tweak this to show more/less than three, but it should be the same number of pages on each side.
- If the current page number is close to the total page count, don't display the right ellipsis.
- The ellipsis links should represent the mid point between the two pages surrounding it. Using your screen shot as an example, the first ellipsis would be for page 4 ((9 - 2) / 2 = 3.5) and the second ellipsis would be for page 22 ((61 - 18) / 2 = 21.5).

Different applications implement these rules a bit differently. Feel free to check out the source code to other applications to see what rules they followed.

Comment: Ok let's forget about ellipsis, the only thing I need is to display Prev/Next buttons, like here: http://d-scribe.de/webtools/jquery-pagination/demo/demo_options.htm, but always showing a fixed number of pagination links, say 5 and is in this part where I have no clue what to do :(

Comment: Why not just use that plug-in?

Comment: Cause it seems quite complicated and I don't even know what to download :S  Btw ,is this http://www.castleproject.org/monorail/documentation/v20/helpers/pagination/index.html#api the  plug-in you suggested?

Comment: I was referring to the d-scribe.de link. If you view source on the demo you can probably find what to download. I've never used a plug-in for pagination.

Comment: @Steven Benitez -but you said you used it in the past?? could you give the exact link? cause I think we're talking about 2 completely different things. And one more thing, you said that adding next/remove buttons was sth easy to do, could you plz give me some guidance with that?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I said that in the past I had used a bean class and a tag file. It wasn't an open source JAR or plug-in, it was just Java code that we wrote for the project. I listed some of the logic that we had implemented for you.

Comment: Here's a tutorial http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-paginate-data-with-php/ on how to do all the pagination work and it seems to meet all my requirements, but it is written in php, and I've never used php before. Could any of you help with the part that deal with the pagination links that are going to be display?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're very close...
Have you looked at replacing your foreach() with a while() loop?.

```
[PREV] [1] [2]

    while starting at 3 and ending at Total - 2

[LAST 2] [results] [NEXT].
```

You can handle the ellipsis with a conditional statement as well (you won't want them to appear all the time - (ie  Prev 1, 2...3,4,5...6, 7, Next).

I've done this exact thing in PHP, but I don't want to paste that in a JSP q/a. (I jumped the gun a little). It just seemed you'd be able to answer your own question with a different perspective to your solution.

Comment: Can you give me more clues? :$

Comment: Now I feel like I should delete my answer all together because I'm unable to post the JSP code...